# Haskell how to print mutable vector

Tags: haskell, vector, printing, mutable

```
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class  (liftIO)
import           Control.Monad.Primitive
import qualified Data.Vector             as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable     as MV

fromList :: [a] -> IO (MV.IOVector a)
fromList = V.thaw . V.fromList

printMV :: PrimMonad m => MV.MVector (PrimState m) a -> m ()
printMV = liftIO . print . V.freeze
```

I want to print `MVector` (surprised that there isn't a show instance). So I have to `freez` it first to `Vector`.
And then I got type errors:

```
Algo/QuickSort.hs:12:11: error: …
    • Couldn't match type ‘PrimState m’ with ‘PrimState m0’
      Expected type: MV.MVector (PrimState m) a -> m ()
        Actual type: MV.MVector (PrimState m0) a -> m ()
      NB: ‘PrimState’ is a non-injective type family
      The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression: liftIO . print . V.freeze
      In an equation for ‘printMV’: printMV = liftIO . print . V.freeze
    • Relevant bindings include
        printMV :: MV.MVector (PrimState m) a -> m ()
          (bound at /home/skell/btree/Algo/QuickSort.hs:12:1)
   |
Compilation failed.
```

I've also tried the `IOVector`

```
printMV :: MV.IOVector a -> IO ()
printMV = liftIO . print . V.freeze
```

This time the error is different:

```
Algo/QuickSort.hs:12:28: error: …
    • Couldn't match type ‘PrimState m0’ with ‘RealWorld’
      Expected type: MV.IOVector a -> m0 (V.Vector a)
        Actual type: MV.MVector (PrimState m0) a -> m0 (V.Vector a)
      The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘V.freeze’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘print . V.freeze’
      In the expression: liftIO . print . V.freeze
   |
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: There can't be a `Show` instance (or at least, can't be the `Show` instance you probably have in mind) because `show` is not permitted to do `IO`, and `IO` is required to read from the vector.

Comment: @DanielWagner So you mean all Haskellers do what I just did in order to print the `vector`?

Comment: Hm. Well, that claim is probably too strong. `freeze`ing is definitely one way; but there are many others, too. For example, one might iterate over indices without freezing, or present the elements in some algorithm-specific order that's more human readable, or translate the vector into a tree because it's actually a linearized heap, or use the vector to create a monadically-computed [brick](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/brick) widget, or, or, or...

Comment: @DanielWagner How do you iterate a `MVector`? I couldn't find a `Foldable` or `Traversable` instance for it. Can I somehow `mapM_ print` it?

Comment: There cannot be `Foldable` or `Traversable` instances for essentially the same reason there cannot be a `Show` instance. But e.g. `mapM_ (MV.read v >=> print) [0 .. MV.length v-1]` works just fine for `IO`-based vectors, where `MV` is `Data.Vector.Mutable`. (Or you can use `MV.unsafeRead` if you're feeling the need for speed. An advanced Haskeller might also write the loop out by hand if they didn't trust list fusion to eliminate the `[0 .. MV.length v-1]`. But those two should happen only after verifying that the speed of this loop actually matters -- when printing it almost never does.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are a couple of things going on - first one solution:

```hs
printMV :: MonadIO m => Show a => PrimMonad m => MV.MVector (PrimState m) a -> m ()
printMV v = do
    fv <- V.freeze v
    liftIO $ print fv
```

So the issues:

- `freeze` is an `m`-action itself so it needs to be bound
- `liftIO` needs an `MonadIO` instance
- in order for `Vector a` to be `Show` - `a` has to be in that class too

---

your second version is similar:

```hs
printMV2 :: Show a => MV.IOVector a -> IO ()
printMV2 v = V.freeze v >>= print
```

- need the `Show` instance for `a`
- need to `>>=` the result of `V.freeze` (same as above - `do` does this implicitly)
- here there is no need for `liftIO` as you are already in it